# Paint component over background

Tags: java, swing, paint, graphics2d

I have a little problem drawing some images.
I am using a JDialog to display the background and a separated class to display the cards (using sprites).

The background displays well but the JPanel don't.

Here is my code :

```
public Main(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();

    //Call the board to draw cards
    Board plateau = new Board(); 

    this.add(plateau);
}

/**
 * Paint the background
 *
 * @param g
 */
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {  
    try {      
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        this.background_image = ImageIO.read(new File(this.background));
        Graphics2D big = this.background_image.createGraphics();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        g2.setPaint(new TexturePaint(this.background_image, rectangle));

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g2.fill(rect);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And the class that should draw the cards :

```
@Override  
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {
        this.image = ImageIO.read(new File("Ressources/images/cardsprite.gif"));

        //4 lines
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //13 rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                //Split one card
                BufferedImage temp = this.image.getSubimage(j * this.CARD_WIDTH,
                        i * this.CARD_HEIGHT, this.CARD_WIDTH, this.CARD_HEIGHT);

                g.drawImage(temp, j * this.CARD_WIDTH,
                        i * this.CARD_HEIGHT, this);
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

If I put the cards drawing class into the paint method of the Main, it works fine.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you are breaking the paint chain, which is preventing your "main" class from painting any of it's children.

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for an overview of the paint process.

You, also, shouldn't be overriding `paint`, but instead, should be overriding `paintComponent` from something that extends `JComponent`.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Basically, you should create a "back ground" panel, which is responsible for painting the background and then add the component responsible for painting the cards on top of it, making sure that it is transparent (`setOpaque(false)`) so the background shows through.

If you're not doing any dynamic effects, you could even us a `JLabel` for the background pane.

You should avoid doing anything in any `paintXxx` method that could be potentially time consuming, like loading images. The paint process should be optimised to allow it to run as fast as possible...